Transistors in LM108 op-amp
I noticed that on the LM108 schematic shown below (also available from https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/lt0108.pdf, page 8):

NPN transistors are drawn in 2 different ways -- some with two lines and some with one line as per:

Does that indicate some difference between the transistors, or is it just inconsistent drawing?  If the transistors are different in some ways, then what are the differences?
Originally, I was thinking that one of the symbols might be for the LM108's input superbeta transistors, but I couldn't reconcile that notion with the rest of the circuit. For one, using superbeta transistors anywhere else don't make much sense given their fragility; for two, the LM108's output is driven by Q18 and Q19, and I find it simply inconceivable to use a fragile superbeta in any of those positions.
Some more, 'insider' info on the LM108: https://www.righto.com/2016/12/inside-lm108-op-amp-superbeta.html

Bob Widlar must have had a lot to do with that design

@D.A.S. indeed that linked document names him.

TLDR yea Bob...  @JasenСлаваУкраїні

Analog Devices's copy of the LM108 retains the same schematic as National Semiconductor's original.
Texas Instruments (which now owns National Semiconductor) has the following to say:

Figure 4 shows a simplified schematic of the LM108. Two kinds of NPN transistors are used on the IC
chip: super gain (primary) transistors which have a current gain of 5000 with a breakdown voltage of 4V
and conventional (secondary) transistors which have a current gain of 200 with an 80V breakdown. These
are differentiated on the schematic by drawing the secondaries with a wider base.

https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa624b/snoa624b.pdf
The superbeta transistors are protected by the circuitry that surrounds them.
All the PNP transistors are "Laterals" and they have a breakdown voltage of 80 volts.

The second stage is a differential amplifier using high gain lateral PNPs [...] These devices
have current gains of 150 and a breakdown voltage of 80V

So it's only the thin-base NPNs that are the fragile super-beta parts.
